# I want hide tool tip background container , because i am using html content in am chart v4

Tags: amcharts

I want to hide tooltip background container , because i am using html content in `amchart4`. I am showing tooltip content using html and our own container like `div` tag and table, but when tooltip shows then a background container is also displayed. Please help to hide it.

[image: Please see attached screen shot]

Comment: If you don't show your code and what you have accomplished, nobody could answer your question.

Comment: if (series._className === ChartTypeEnum.COLUMN_SERIES) {
                series.columns.template.tooltipPosition = ChartPropertyEnum.DEFAULT_TOOLTIP_POSITION; 
                series.columns.template.events.on(ChartPropertyEnum.TOOL_TIP_EVENT, function (ev) {                    
                    series.columns.template.tooltipHTML = ModifyTooltipHtmlOfAMJSCharts(ev, series.name, this);    
                    series.tooltip.html = ModifyTooltipHtmlOfAMJSCharts(ev, series.name, this);   
                   
                }, this);

            }

Comment: can you just edit your original post and add the code there? also can you create a jsfiddle (https://www.jsfiddle.net) so we can have something to play with?

Comment: @Rahul.kmar If the background was hidden so it was transparent, you would still get the border around it, and the tooltip. Are you sure that's what you want? Why not adjust the border (stroke) of the tooltip itself instead of having a border around your HTML table?